# Swapping items in a QML GridView?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I've been trying to swap elements in the following example:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/draganddrop-views-gridview-qml.html

If the elements that I am dragging are next to each other, it works fine of course.
But what I would like to do is to be able to swap even elements that are on the same y axis, eg. index 0 and 4. The problem is that the elements are laid out from left to right. Is there a way to make a grid like this keep the items floating, and be able to swap any 2 elements, or do I always have to remove/add elements in order to swap them, which causes the (undesired) behavior in my case?

Comment: This is four years after this question was first asked. I've posted an answer to [_a similar question_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329311/swap-elements-in-a-gridview/53386253#53386253). See if that may help.